# How to upload a new version of my app to App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm a beginner at IOS development and I made an app with React-Native and Expo. I uploaded the first version of my app to the App Store Connect and I want to push a new version with some bug fixes. When I try to put it up, Transporter gives me this error:

[image]

How do I fix this issue? Everyone is talking about something in XCode but I'm not using that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update you App version.
File `project.pbxproj` line with `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = ...;`